# I'm passing three 3 parameter on a javascript function but it only get's the first parameter what could be wrong

Tags: javascript, laravel, function, bootstrap-modal

//this is the data i get from controller ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

```
//this is where i call the function fun_view() where im passing the name, company_name, mobile_phone

<td><a href="" data-id="" class="display" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="fun_view('{{ $dat->name,$dat->company_name,$dat->mobile_phone }}')"><?php echo $dat->name;?></a></td>

//this is fun_view function 'im calling

function fun_view(name, company_name, mobile) {
    var name = name;
    var company_name = company_name;
    var mobile = mobile;
    alert(name);
    alert(company_name);
    alert(mobile);
    document.getElementById("view_name").innerHTML = name;
    document.getElementById("view_company_name").innerHTML = company_name;
    document.getElementById("view_mobile").innerHTML = mobile;
    return name, company_name, mobile;
}

//this is where is display the result of fun_view function
//this is where i display the variable that i should be getting on fun_view() javascript function
```

Comment: oh, I see. you pass the parameters as `'{{ $dat->name,$dat->company_name,$dat->mobile_phone }}'` - a single string

Comment: this `return name, company_name, mobile;` is not how one returns multiple values from a function - not a problem in your code, since the return value is never used anyway

Comment: shouldn´t it be {{ $dat->name}},{{$dat->company_name}},{{$dat->mobile_phone }} ?

Comment: my guess is `'{{ $dat->name}}','{{$dat->company_name}}','{{$dat->mobile_phone }}'`

Comment: Also you can not put href="" make it to look like this href="#" or href="javascript:void(0)"

Answer (score 2):

you're wrapping all variables under a single quote:

It needs to be:

```
fun_view('{{ $dat->name}}','{{$dat->company_name}}','{{$dat->mobile_phone }}')
```

In addition you're not allowed to return multiple values from a function, you need something like:

```
return { name: name, company_name: company_name, mobile_phone: mobile_phone }
```

Example usage:

```
 var result = fun_view('a','b','c');

 console.log(result.name, result.company_name, result.mobile_phone);
```

In addition you should use `href='javascript:void(0)'` as a href. This will prevent the page from redirecting. You could also use `#` .

Comment: @FooBar not sure I'm getting you